# I do try to fill a combo box in front-end by a field value from a database

Tags: mysql, node.js

### Here is the code in back-end

```
function get_position(callback) {
        tempCont.query('SELECT * from `governorates`',function (error, results) {
        if (error) callback(null);
        console.log("from query = " + results);
        callback(results);
    });
}

get_position(function (ido) {
    if (!!error) {
        console.log('Error in getting positions to combo box');}
    else {
res.render('./register', { errors: null, positions: ido });
             }

})}
```

### Here is the code in front_end

```
<input type=text list=browsers >
<datalist id=browsers >
    <% positions.forEach(function(item){ %>
     <option> <%= item %> 
    <%});%>
 </datalist>
 <br>
```

### here is the result

in the combo box [object object] not names of governorates

Comment: you need to specify the column name in options like `item.column1` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=text list=browsers >
<datalist id=browsers >
    <% positions.forEach(function(item){ %>
     <option> <%= item.role_name %> 
    <%});%>
 </datalist>
 <br>
```